# Code Coverage Issue on trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, community

I have a trigger and an apex class, When i deploy them from staging to production I get the following error. What Should i do ? I have a week experience in salesfroce.

**Issue**

Code Coverage Failure
Your organization's code coverage is 71%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment. Also, the following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.
AccountCallout

**Code**   **Trigger**

```
trigger AccountCallout on Account (after update) {
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        // make the asynchronous web service callout

        WebServiceCallout.sendNotification(a.Name, 
           a.Email__c, a.BillingStreet,a.Country_of_Headquarters__c,
           a.Any_other_questions_of_operation__c, a.Website, a.Year_of_formation__c,
           a.Legal_Status__c,a.Legal_Status_Other__c, a.Mission_Statement__c,
           a.Mission_Statement_Other__c, a.Sector_of_Operation__c, a.Sector_Other__c,
           a.What_does_this_Enterprise_do__c, a.Parent_Company_C__c, a.NumberOfEmployees,
           a.How_did_you_hear_about_Connect__c, a.Why_interested_in_Connect_programme__c, a.Innovative_idea__c,
           a.Benefits_of_your_innovation__c, a.Seeking_a_partner_Requirements__c, a.Any_other_info__c,
           a.Value_enterprise_provides__c, a.Improve_health_or_agri_food_prospects__c,
           a.Opportunities_to_improve_diversify_grow__c );        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can hust point me in the right direction

Comment: You are calling out in for loop. You should make the trigger bulkified.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have test classes? If so, post them in your question. If not, write them. If it still doesn't work - post a question asking what you want and showing us what you tried. SFSE is a Q&A site where you can find help if you also show some effort you did yourself.

Comment: @Novarg : Duly Noted sir, thanks for the info. I had no idea regarding test classes before today. So i was just looking for a way to write test classes.

Comment: tushar, I suggest you go to the [Trailhead Modules](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules) and locate the Test Class module to learn how to write them properly. There's also a module on Triggers. In your case, also look at the documentation on making Mock callouts.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for info  +1, I am looking for a basic structure to make a test case on trigger, Since i find salesforce documentation difficult to understand

Comment: (1) the interface you defined to `WebServiceCallout.sendNotification` has so many parameters/arguments. You really should just be passing the Account `a`; (2) callouts in a trigger loop will cause governor issues - you need a bulkified async pattern to do this robustly or the next Data Loader pass on Account will blow up

Answer (score 2):

Yes as mentioned your code coverage should be greater than 75% to deploy.

1. Create appropriate test class for this trigger
2. In the test class make sure to update the Account object at-least once

**Ref:**

- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_To_Test_Your_Apex_Triggers

And also its good to keep in mind the best practices:

**Ref:**

- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code
- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops

**EDIT**

Simplest test which would cover your trigger would be:

```
@isTest 
  private class AccountCalloutTest {
      static testMethod void validateCallout() {
         Account acc = new Account(Name='Test Account');
         insert acc;
         update acc;
      }
  }
```

*Note:*

The above test just takes your test coverage up. If you are really interested in testing the whole functionality I would recommend doing real System.assert to validate the behavior of your artifact.

Comment: I think it's #1 he needs help with :)

Comment: What will be the shortest test class example

Comment: mkorman sure, I was thinking he needs pointers to proceed. @tushar I updated the answer with a sample test.

Comment: @karthikselva I get the following error after writing your test case :
esttrigger validateCallout System.NullPointerException: null argument for JSONGenerator.writeStringField()
Stack Trace: Class.System.JSONGenerator.writeStringField: line 178, column 1 Class.WebServiceCallout.sendNotification: line 27, column 1